# PyYaml "include file" and yaml aliases (anchors/references)

Tags: yaml, pyyaml, cross-reference

I had a large YAML file with a massive use of YAML anchors and references, for example:

```
warehouse:
  obj1: &obj1
    key1: 1
    key2: 2
specific:
  spec1: 
    <<: *obj1
  spec2:
    <<: *obj1
    key1: 10
```

The file got too large, so I looked for a solution that will allow me split to 2 files: `warehouse.yaml` and `specific.yaml`, and to include the `warehouse.yaml` inside the `specific.yaml`. I read [this simple article](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577613-yaml-include-support/), which describes how I can use PyYAML to achieve that, but it also says that the merge key(<<) is not supported.

I really got an error:

> yaml.composer.ComposerError: found undefined alias 'obj1

when I tried to go like that.

So, I started looking for alternative way and I got confused because I don't really know much about PyYAML.

Can I get the desired merge key support? Any other solutions for my problem?

Comment: I hope you are aware that there is no need to have the anchor for a value to be the same string as the correspoding key (`obj1`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Crucial for the handling of anchors and aliases in PyYAML is the dict `anchors` that is part of the `Composer`. It maps anchor to nodes so that aliases can be looked up. It existence is limited  by the existence of the `Composer`, which is a composite element of the `Loader` that you use.

That `Loader` class only exists during the time of the call to `yaml.load()` so there is no trivial way to extract this afterwards: first you would have to make the instance of the `Loader()` persist and then make sure that the  normal `compose_document()` method is not called (which among other things does `self.anchors = {}`, to be clean for the next document (in a single stream)).

To further complicate things if you would have `warehouse.yaml`:

```yaml
warehouse:
  obj1: &obj1
    key1: 1
    key2: 2
```

and `specific.yaml`:

```yaml
warehouse: !include warehouse.yaml
specific:
  spec1:
    <<: *obj1
  spec2:
    <<: *obj1
    key1: 10
```

you would never get this to work with your snippet, even if you could preserve, extract and pass on the anchor information because the composer handling `specific.yaml` will much earlier encountering a non-defined alias than the tag `!include` gets used for construction (and filling `anchors`).

What you can do to circumvent this problem is to include `specific.yaml`

```yaml
specific:
  spec1:
    <<: *obj1
  spec2:
    <<: *obj1
    key1: 10
```

from `warehouse.yaml`:

```yaml
warehouse:
  obj1: &obj1
    key1: 1
    key2: 2
specific: !include specific.yaml
```

, or include both in a third file. **Please note that the key `specific` is in both files**.

With those two files run:

```py
import sys
from ruamel import yaml

def my_compose_document(self):
    self.get_event()
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
    self.get_event()
    # self.anchors = {}    # <<<< commented out
    return node

yaml.SafeLoader.compose_document = my_compose_document

# adapted from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577613-yaml-include-support/
def yaml_include(loader, node):
    with open(node.value) as inputfile:
        return list(my_safe_load(inputfile, master=loader).values())[0]
#              leave out the [0] if your include file drops the key ^^^

yaml.add_constructor("!include", yaml_include, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)


def my_safe_load(stream, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader, master=None):
    loader = Loader(stream)
    if master is not None:
        loader.anchors = master.anchors
    try:
        return loader.get_single_data()
    finally:
        loader.dispose()

with open('warehouse.yaml') as fp:
    data = my_safe_load(fp)
yaml.safe_dump(data, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False)
```

which gives:

```yaml
specific:
  spec1:
    key1: 1
    key2: 2
  spec2:
    key1: 10
    key2: 2
warehouse:
  obj1:
    key1: 1
    key2: 2
```

If your `specific.yaml` would not have the top-level key `specific`:

```yaml
spec1:
  <<: *obj1
spec2:
  <<: *obj1
  key1: 10
```

then replace the last line of `yaml_include()` with:

```py
return my_safe_load(inputfile, master=loader)
```

The above was done with [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package) and tested on Python 2.7 and 3.6. By changing the import it will work with PyYAML as well.

---

With the new `ruamel.yaml` API the above can be much simplified, because the `loader` handed to the `yaml_include()` constructor knows about the `YAML` instance, but of course you still need an adapted `compose_document` that doesn't destroy anchors. Assuming the `specific.yaml` **without** top-level key `specific`, the following gives the same output as before.

```py
import sys
from ruamel.std.pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, version_info

yaml = YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)
yaml.default_flow_style = False


def my_compose_document(self):
    self.parser.get_event()
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
    self.parser.get_event()
    # self.anchors = {}    # <<<< commented out
    return node

yaml.Composer.compose_document = my_compose_document

# adapted from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577613-yaml-include-support/
def yaml_include(loader, node):
    y = loader.loader
    yaml = YAML(typ=y.typ, pure=y.pure)  # same values as including YAML
    yaml.composer.anchors = loader.composer.anchors
    return yaml.load(Path(node.value))

yaml.Constructor.add_constructor("!include", yaml_include)

data = yaml.load(Path('warehouse.yaml'))
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Comment: As the comment on the activestate recipe indicates, that include mechanism is far from robust. One should at least subclass `YAML` to include code to test against files being processed, to prevent infinite recursion. By using `typ='safe'` you cannot instantiate arbitrary objects, although abusing the `!include` as is can crash your program.

Comment: This post is quite old. Although there is a most recent update from @maciej about an extension for [ramuel.yaml](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml) that add the "!include" mechanism out-of-the-box => [ramuel.yaml.include](https://github.com/Tristan-Sweeney-CambridgeConsultants/ccorp_yaml_include). It's not maintained, though. Do you plan to add such feature to your package in the future?

Comment: @muxevola I was not aware of that answer, nor of the repository mentioned in there. I'll try to look into that when I have some time.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that someone has now solved this problem as an extension of ruamel.yaml.

`pip install ruamel.yaml.include` [(source on GitHub)](https://github.com/Tristan-Sweeney-CambridgeConsultants/ccorp_yaml_include)

To get the desired output above:

**warehouse.yml**

```
obj1: &obj1
  key1: 1
  key2: 2
```

**specific.yml**

```
specific:
  spec1: 
    <<: *obj1
  spec2:
    <<: *obj1
    key1: 10
```

Your code would be:

```
from ccorp.ruamel.yaml.include import YAML

yaml = YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True

with open('specific.yml', 'r') as ymlfile:
    return yaml.load(ymlfile)
```

It also includes a handy !exclude function if you wanted to *not* have the warehouse key in your output. If you only wanted the specific key, your `specific.yml` could begin with:

```
!exclude includes:
- !include warehouse.yml
```

In that case, your warehouse.yml could also include the top-level `warehouse:` key.

Comment: Myfile.yaml:
>>
my_key1:
  - *obj1
  - name: my_obj1
>>>
pip install ccorp-yaml-include
from ccorp.ruamel.yaml.include import YAML
yaml = YAML(typ='safe', pure=True)
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
p = "C:\\Users\\yaml\\Myfile.yaml"
f = open(p, 'r')
yaml.load(f)
>>>
ERROR: ruamel.yaml.composer.ComposerError: found undefined alias 'obj1'